# how do I reference a list array I created in a different class into a another

Tags: java

I am new to Java, and this is project I need to deliver today. :(

I am not sure how to reference the array objects I created in another class.
It works if i do a normal array, but not with arraylist.
When I do this:

```
for(Integer k=0; k < run.accounts.length; k++) {
            if((run.accounts[k][0].compareTo(id) == 0) &&
                    (run.accounts[k[1].compareTo(p)== 0))
```

It just doesn't know anything about my accounts array.

```
public class  Users {
    public List<List<String>> accounts = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

    public Users(){
        accounts.add(Arrays.asList("207860830", "0171", "active","admin"));
```

//          [ ... ]
            accounts.add(Arrays.asList("110000200", "1270", "active","regular"));

```
    }
    public void DatosUsers() {
    }


} // end class Users
```

---

// IN A DIFFERENT CLASS

```
public class LOGINING {


    public void login() {


    Users run = new Users();
    run.DatosUsers();


        for (Integer k = 0; k < run.accounts.length; k++) {
            if ((run.accounts[k][0].compareTo(id) == 0) && (run.accounts[k][1].compareTo(p) == 0)) {
                auth = true;
                System.out.println(auth);
                break;
            }
            {
                auth = false;
                System.out.println(auth);
            }
        }

        [ ... ]
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about what is happening? Are you getting an exception or is something just not working?

Comment: In my  public class "Users" I declared an array, and filled it out with some data. I am trying to call that data in my other class LOGINING, in am doing some conditions iterating over the array I created in the other class, but the array elements are not recognized, I do run.accounts within the LOGINING class it says the array does not exist. :'(

Comment: And it does not work, it is ERRORING OUT in red. It says ARRAY REQUIRED, BUT <LIST<STRING>> FOUND.

Comment: You're trying to access a List as if it were an array using array indices, so it makes sense that the compiler will complain. You access List items using the `get(...)` method, not using array indices. Please take a look at a List tutorial that I'm sure Google can help you find.

Comment: Damn @HovercraftFullOfEels you answered it while I was typing. :) I'll add the tutorial / api in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This how you iterate through a List.

```
for (List<String> list : run.accounts) {
        if ((list.get(0).compareTo(id) == 0) && (list.get(0).compareTo(p) == 0)) {
            auth = true;
            System.out.println(auth);
            break;
        }else {
            auth = false;
            System.out.println(auth);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using the [x][y] notation which List doesn't support.
either iterate using

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("a");
list.add("b");

for (String s : list) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

or use indexes but then use .get

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("a");
list.add("b");

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) ) {
    System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```

If this isn't the problem then you have to be more specific (for instance, list the exact line that isn't compiling, and the compilation error)

For reference, make sure you read:
[The List API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)
[Collections tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaCollections/article.html)